# Powershell Get-Process missing parameter?

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm working on `Windows Server 2012 R2` with `Powershell 4.0` and can execute `Get-Process -IncludeUserName` while using elevated user rights as an admin. But when I try running the same command on a `Windows Server 2008 R2` with `Powershell 3.0` while using the same elevated user rights, the parameter `-IncludeUserName` isn't found. What's missing on the 2nd system for executing the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Technet Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832(v=wps.620).aspx) for `get-process` the `-IncludeUserName` parameter was not available in the `get-process` cmdlet until Powershell 4.  You'll need to install the updated version in order to gain access to that feature.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the difference between V3 and V4 is that V4 brings the additional ability to include the username of the process.

I don't have V3 to test with, but I do have V2, and it's not available there.